# i can not install laravel passport

Tags: php, laravel

```
composer require laravel/passport ^v1
result command
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - doctrine/instantiator 1.1.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - doctrine/instantiator 1.1.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.22) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for doctrine/instantiator (installed at 1.1.0) -> satisfiable by doctrine/instantiator[1.1.0].



Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.22",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "laravel/passport": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

how can i solved it

Comment: `requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.22)`.

Comment: install PHP 7.1?

Comment: Please read your error messages carefully before opening a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install php 7.1 and you will be fine.

For ubuntu
https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-and-configure-php-70-or-php-71-on-ubuntu-16-04

For windows
http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your php version to be 7, after that you have to re install your composer and make sure that it will take correct php version